# Count how many times 'male' and 'female' appears in a field in access database (asp.net, C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access

I would like my asp.net application to count how times 'male' and 'female' appear in a certain field upon button click. This is what I have so far and would like the values to return in a label. How can I return those values in separate labels? One for Male and one for Female.

```
protected void btnRetrieve_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string constr = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=accessdatabase.mdb";
string cmdstr = "SELECT Gender FROM StudentList WHERE (GENDER = 'Male') OR (GENDER = 'Female')";

OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand(cmdstr, con);
MaleLabel = ????

}
```

Comment: You want `SELECT Count(Gender)..` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your query to

```
select gender, count(gender)
from StudentList
group by gender
```

At that point you can retrieve the gender and the count directly from the results.